# other way to upload files in library

Tags: document-library, file-upload, sharepoint-server

I have requirement to create an alternate link to upload files in document library as OOTB link (i.e.Add new document)gives option to user to overwrite existing file.(or new version of existing file if versioning is enabled)
Any idea..?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to create a link that points to a specific document library to upload documents. I would do the following for non-code solution:

1. Go to the document library
2. Right click on the link that says **Add Document ** and then select **Copy shortcut **
3. Create a link and paste the text copied from the previous step.

Comment: no..I dont mean that. I just want to avoid user's mistakes to overwrite existing file if name is same.! If you check, there is by default check-box (checked), while uploading the document. in other statement i don't want to let user overwrite any existing file if name is same.